# How can I connect two computers, with one without a display, keyboard, or mouse?

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

I have two computers. One is my main laptop (fully functional x64 Windows 11 machine with keyboard, mouse, display etc) and the other is an old 32-bit desktop running Windows 7 (unknown SP) without any keyboard, mouse, display etc. It powers on nicely and seems like it's on the Windows 7 desktop. (The admin user account on the desktop has no password so it's "automatically" logged in after I boot up the computer). I have an Ethernet cable and both computers have ports for Ethernet.

Is there any way I could get to control the desktop from my laptop, via Remote Desktop Connection or SSH or other means?

Comment: How are you going to configure RDP or any other software, without any HID or GUI?

Comment: Get an inexpensive monitor and use that with a KVM switch to accomplish what you want.

Comment: 1) Move the monitor, mouse, and keyboard to 32bit machine.  2) If PRO, configure remote desktop.  If HOME, install and configure VNC. 3) Use either RDC or VNC on your primary laptop to make sure it works.  4) Move everything back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to drag the bulky old 300 pound bastard to my living room and hook it up to the TV via HDMI, and I enabled Remote Desktop manually in Control Panel using nothing but a barely functioning mouse from 2009 and the Windows on-screen keyboard. Thankfully my father was generous enough to have a Professional edition of Windows installed so it was much easier than it could have been.

You gotta do what you gotta do, I guess.